# Running Java GUI tests on GitHub using xvfb

Tags: user-interface, github, automated-tests, github-actions, xvfb

I've got some basic automated GUI tests for my Java desktop application that work when running on my Windows desktop. On GitHub they fail with

> java.awt.AWTError at X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:-2

I started from the default `Java CI with Gradle` workflow, and have added some steps attempting to set up xvfb so it has a display to work with, but it's still failing. Is there a way I can modify the workflow so that X11 is available for the tests?

```json
name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'adopt'
    - name: Set up virtual X11
      run: sudo apt-get install xvfb
    - name: Start virtual frame buffer
      run: Xvfb :19 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
    - name: set display
      run: export DISPLAY=:19
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up splitting the GUI tests off using JUnit `@Tag`s, and then adding separate gradle tasks:

```
task nonGuiTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        excludeTags 'gui'
    }
}

task guiTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags 'gui'
    }
}
```

then in the workflow

- I run `build -x test` initially
- then run the non-GUI tests
- then use the `GabrielBB/xvfb-action@v1` action to set up xvfb
- then run the GUI tests

```yaml
name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'adopt'
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build -x test
    - name: headless tests
      run: ./gradlew nonGuiTest
    - name: GUI tests
      uses: GabrielBB/xvfb-action@v1
      with:
        run: ./gradlew guiTest
```